# rails - validate product ordered has the available quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two related validations on separate models.  I can validate one way but not another.  The post validation works: if I try to change the quantity available as the seller, and people have already ordered some of it, it (correctly) won't let me change the quantity below the amount ordered already.

The order validation does not work: if I try changing the order amount to more than is available, it lets me.  It checks only the **current** sum (I guess before the save), and does not notice the buyer trying to sneak out more than what's available.  When I try and change the order back to less than what is available, it won't let me, checking the current sum ordered (before save).

I also tried validating the quantity of the order + the remaining available stock (available -sum ordered), but have the same problem.

How would I get the validation to check what the quantity would be *after* the save, and then not save it should the value be invalid?  It would have to work also for editing an order

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy

    attr_accessible :quantity, :deadline, :product_id, :event_id

    validate :quantity_gt_ordered

    def quantity_gt_ordered
       self.errors.add(:quantity, " - People have already ordered more than this") unless self.quantity >= self.sum_orders
    end

    def sum_orders
        self.orders.sum(:quantity)
    end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :post

    attr_accessible :order_price, :post_id, :user_id, :quantity

    validate :quantity_is_available

    def quantity_is_available
       self.errors.add(:quantity, " - Please order only what's available") unless self.sum_post_orders <= self.post.quantity
    end

    def sum_post_orders
      Order.where(:post => self.post).sum(:quantity)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to compare to the available quantity minus the ordered quantity:

```
available_quantity = self.post.quantity - self.sum_post_order
if quantity > available_quantity
  self.errors.add(:quantity, " - Please order only what's available")
end
```

And also make sure your `sum_post_orders` doesn't include the current order:

```
Order.where("id != ?", self.id).where(:post => self.post).sum(:quantity)
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that I should be able to.  I tried your code but it still lets me order more than the quantity available (and then keeps me from changing it back to a valid amount)

Comment: That works until I try and edit an existing order: the current quantity ordered, although valid, can be greater than what is available to other buyers.  It adds an error when I edit and save the order without changing the quantity

Comment: Maybe update `sum_post_orders` to not include the current order? `Order.where("id != ?", self.id).where(:post => self.post).sum(:quantity)`